# How can I let the web page automatically navigate based on time

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I currently use laravel-5.8 and I want the welcome page can automatically jump to the thank you page when the time is after Oct  26th, 2019. That is, after Oct 26th, every time you open the localhost 8000, the web browser will show thank you page instead of welcome page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a conditional redirect in the controller function of the route.

So you check if the current date is equal to, or greater than, the date you want. If so - redirect to the thank you route. Otherwise serve the welcome view.

```
Carbon::parse("Oct 27th, 2019"); // will return 2019-10-27 00:00:00.0.
```

So as soon as you pass the last second of Oct 26th you'll be equal or greater to this date.

You could do something like this (with better function and route names of course):

***routes/web.php***

```
    Route::get('/', 'MyController@welcomeFunction')->name('welcome');
    Route::get('/', 'MyController@thanksFunction')->name('thanks');
```

***app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php***

```
function welcomeFunction() {

        $now = Carbon::now();
        $targetDate = Carbon::parse("Oct 27th, 2019");

        if ($now >= $targetDate ) {
            return redirect(route('thanks'));
        }

        return view('welcome');
}

function thanksFunction() {
        return view('thanks');
}
```